# Simulink data types

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm reading an IMU on the arduino board with a s-function block in simulink by double or single data types though I just need 2 decimals precision as ("xyz.ab").I want to improve the performance with changing data types and wonder that;

is there a way to decrease the precision to 2 decimals in s-function block or by adding/using any other conversion blocks/codes in the simulink aside from using fixed-point tool?

[image: Sfunctionblock]

Comment: No, the way to get fixed-point data is to use the fixed-point toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For true fixed point transfer, fixed-point toolbox is the most general answer, as stated in Phil's comment.

However, to avoid toolbox use, you could also devise your own fix-point integer format and add a block that takes a floating point input and convert it into an integer format (and vice versa on the output).

E.g. If you know the range is 327.68 < var < 327.67 you could just define your float as an int16 divided by 10. In a matlab function block you would then just say

y=int16(u*100.0);

to convert the input to the S-function. 
On the output it would be a reversal

y=double(u)/100.0;

(Eml/matlab function code can be avoided by using multiply, divide and convert blocks.)

However, be mindful of the bits available and that the scaling (*,/) operations is done on the floating point rather than the integer.

2^(nrOfBits-1)-1 shows you what range you can represent including signeage. For unsigned types uint8/16/32 the range is 2^(nrOfBits)-1. Then you use the scaling to fit the representable bit into your used floating point range. The scaled range divided by 2^nrOfBits will tell you what the resolution will be (how large are the steps).

You will need to scale the variables correspondingly on the Arduino side as well when you go to an integer interface of this type. (I'm assuming you have access to that code - if not it'd be hard to use any other interface than what is already provided)

Note that the intXX(doubleVar*scale) will always truncate the values to integer. If you need proper rounding you should also include the round function, e.g.:

int16(round(doubleVar*scale));

You don't need to use a base 10 scale, any scaling and offsets can be used, but it's easier to make out numbers manually if you keep to base 10 (i.e. 0.1 10.0 100.0 1000.0 etc.).

As a final note, if the Arduino code interface is floating point (single/double) and can't be changed to integer type; you will not get any speedup from rounding decimals since the full floating point is what will be is transferred anyway. Even if you do manage to reduce the data a bit using integers I suspect this might not give a huge speedup unless you transfer large amounts of data. The interface code will have a comparatively large overhead anyway.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful answer.